# Magento 2 Point of sale - Supermax POS

Tags: magento2, pos

I noticed a new POS extension showing on magento marketplace for magento 2 and I wondered if anyone had any experience of it?

It's called supermax POS.  https://store.anyhowinfo.com/point-of-sale/supermax-magento2-point-of-sale.html

It looks pretty clean and neat and the demo appears to be good.  I can't find any real number of reviews or in depth reviews of any kind.  And the last thing I need is a dud POS extension full of bugs.
Thanks
Barry

Comment: So what is your problem and how do you want to solve it?

Comment: I need a fast reliable POS extension to use in a shop that works on multiple devices (desktop and ipad) and ideally has a 1 off payment with no monthly charges and is not charged per device.  It also needs to sync with my web site stock, work on and offline, offer the ability to checkout items which appear out of stock and the ability to add custom items ad-hoc and the ability to apply custom discounts per item.  Another important thing is that if we request a bug fix that the bug fix is included in updated versions and we don't continually run into the same issues if wee update the version.

Comment: Your question looks like an off-topic on this site. Should you look for a system consultant and ask? [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)